# WPF not applying default styles defined in MergedDictionaries?

Tags: c#, wpf, .net-4.0

In a WPF application I defined default control styles in separate resource dictionaries (e.g. "ButtonStyle.xaml"), and added them as merged dictionaries to a resource dictionary named "ResDictionary.xaml".

If I refer this "ResDictionary.xaml" as merged dictionary in my App.xaml, the default styles are not applied. However, if I refer the "ButtonStyle.xaml", it works correctly.

If I recompile the same code in .NET 3.5 or 3.0, it recognizes and applies the default styles referred in "App.xaml" through "ResDictionary.xaml", but not in .NET 4.0.

At runtime if I check the Application.Current.Resources dictionary, the default styles are there, but they are not applied, only if I specify the Style property explicitly in the Button control.

Are there any solutions to refer a resource dictionary (containig default styles) this way in .NET 4.0?

---

App.xaml:

```
<Application.Resources>
  <ResourceDictionary>
    <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
      <ResourceDictionary Source="Styles/ResDictionary.xaml"/>
    </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
  </ResourceDictionary>
</Application.Resources>
```

ResDictionary.xaml:

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
    <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        <ResourceDictionary Source="Default/ButtonStyle.xaml"/>
    </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

ButtonStyle.xaml:

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
    <Style TargetType="Button">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Yellow"/>
    </Style>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

Comment: This seems really weird (just confirmed it myself). The WPF 4 migration issues http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee941656.aspx#windows_presentation_foundation_wpf doesn't seem to mention this either. Unless its the note about frozen and immutable resources?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a sort-of fix for this, but I’ve only been able to make it work at the window level (not the application level).

In order to include a WPF 4.0 resource from a separate project, the resource must be added as a resource in the *window’s* code behind. The statement belongs in the window’s constructor, prior to the InitializeComponent method call:

```
public ControlsWindow()
{
    this.Resources = Application.LoadComponent(new Uri("[WPF 4.0 ResourceProjectName];Component/[Directory and File Name within project]", UriKind.Relative)) as ResourceDictionary;
    InitializeComponent();
}
```

Note: Replace the '[WPF 4.0 ResourceProjectName]' text with your resource's project name.  Also, the '[Directory and File Name within project]' needs to be replaced with the relative location of the resource file (like 'Themes/StandardTheme.xaml')

I go into more details about this issue [here](http://www.wpfreakystyley.com/News/ResourcesIssues.aspx).

Comment: I added your code to the App.xaml.cs constructor, and the default styles worked.
Thanks!

Comment: Yeah, I probably should have mentioned that: the standard (implicit) styles will work when the resource is added to the app.xaml.cs file, but the explicit styles will not... which is strange because it's exactly the opposite of what happens when the resource is added in the XAML file (app.xaml).

Comment: Does anyone know of any workarounds other then this?  It doesn't seem like the logical way this should work.

Answer (score 23):

The best solution is to **add a dummy default style** in the resource dictionary where you merge all resources together.

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">

<ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    <ResourceDictionary Source="Style/Button.xaml"/>
</ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>

<Style TargetType="Control" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type Control}}" />
```

Comment: Works great! I remember this issue with Silverlight too. Your given style doesn't work though--complains of a circular reference. This works fine: <Style TargetType="Control" />

Answer (score 4):

This could be caused by a known bug when there is a single style in application.resources within app.xaml when not using a startupuri.

The fix is to add an additional style like this...

```
...
   <Style x:Key="unused" />
</Application.Resources>
```

for more details check out this link.... http://bengribaudo.com/blog/2010/08/19/106/bug-single-application-resources-entry-ignored

Comment: Seriously? I hate Microsoft ._.
I have been searching for this WAAY too long and this bug still persists in VS2013.3.
Thanks a lot for the solution!

Comment: +1 You saved my day. Not sure why this wasn't noticed much. Thanks a lot.