# WPF Style for base window not applied in App.xaml, but is in Themes/Generic.xaml

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-controls

I am in the process of creating a base window class for most of my windows to derive from. Obviously the best solution for this was a separate class, and a style that applies to it.

The issue is that the `<Style ../>` I have is not being applied when it is in `App.Resources`. That is, if it's defined in an external `ResourceDictionary`, and merged into `App.xaml`'s resources, or a local dictionary and merged, or placed inline into `App.Resources`. The `<Style ../>` is, however, applied when it is placed into `Themes/Generic.xaml`.

The problem can be demonstrated without doing anything special at all in the base window, apart from overriding the `DefaultStyleKeyProperty`.

Below is `ThemeWindow`:

```
public class ThemeWindow : Window
{
    static ThemeWindow()
    {
        DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(ThemeWindow), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(typeof(ThemeWindow)));
    }
}
```

Here is the very simple `<Style ../>` I am trying to apply (it makes the `Window` background red, nothing more):

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type testing:ThemeWindow}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type testing:ThemeWindow}">
                <Grid>
                    <Grid.Background>
                        <SolidColorBrush Color="Red"/>
                    </Grid.Background>
                    <AdornerDecorator>
                        <ContentPresenter />
                    </AdornerDecorator>
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

The `MainWindow` that uses `ThemeWindow`, is simply the following XAML:

```
<testing:ThemeWindow x:Class="Testing.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:testing="clr-namespace:Testing"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <Button Content="Button" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="125,83,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75"/>
    </Grid>
</testing:ThemeWindow>
```

Now, as stated, if you place that `Style` in its own `ResourceDictionary`, and include it like this:

```
<App.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="/Themes/ThemeWindow.xaml" />
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</App.Resources>
```

.. it does not work. If you inline the style straight into `App.Resources`, it does not work.

The *only* situation I can find it working is to call the `ResourceDictionary` xaml `Generic.xaml`, and place it into the `Themes/` directory of the application.

I am wondering exactly why this is happening.

My only theory is that when WPF sees a control type, it will head over to `Themes`, and scan all `ResourceDictionary`s for the type, then fall back to `Generic.xaml` and load it. This doesn't explain why it would not load if the `<Style />` is available in a merged `ResourceDictionary` though. **Note** that it does work if the `MergedDictionary` is placed into `Generic.xaml`, for obvious reasons.

I'm perfectly fine with having to merge the `ResourceDictionary` into `Generic.xaml` if that's what I have to do. I just want to get down at the technical details as to why it needs to be like this.

Screenshots of this not working / working:
[image: Broken Image]
[image: Working Image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have a simple workaround that would allow you to set your Style in you app.xaml.

Define your style in app.xaml like this :

```
<Style x:Key="{x:Type testing:ThemeWindow}" TargetType="{x:Type testing:ThemeWindow}">
```

And change your ThemWindow to this :

```
public class ThemeWindow : Window
{
    static ThemeWindow()
    {
        StyleProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(ThemeWindow), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(GetDefautlStyle()));
    }

    private static Style GetDefautlStyle()
    {
        if (defaultStyle == null)
        {
            defaultStyle = Application.Current.FindResource(typeof(ThemeWindow)) as Style;
        }
        return defaultStyle;
    }

    private static Style defaultStyle = null;
}
```

It does not really solve the question, but that would allow you to achieve what you need !

**EDIT :** Looking at [DefaultStyleKey](http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.defaultstylekey.aspx) reference, it's clearly stated that it's used for *theme style lookup*. That explains why it won't find it in app.xaml or any other dictionary. It will only search in Theme dictionaries. So you either have to define your style in a Theme Dictionary, or to use the Style property directly as in the above example.

Comment: Why do you store `defaultStyle` in a static variable? Given that this is called from the static constructor it will only be called once ...

Comment: I wrote that code more than two years ago so I don't honestly remember the motivations behing this static field. You are obviously right and this field is not necessary.

Answer (score 0):

I come around the following solution already discussed in stackoverflow. it would required to add in the load component when load of the application.

[Refer Solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2753651/wpf-not-applying-default-styles-defined-in-mergeddictionaries)

Comment: Unfortunately, that's not the same issue.